# Classic ASP: How to bind dynamic label name in email body

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I want to bind the label value (which dynamically loads) into email body.

```
objMessage.TextBody=objMessage.TextBody & XXXXX & ": " & Request("Parts") & vbCrLf  

Dim PartsDesc
PartsDesc = request.querystring("partsdesc") 

 <%
    Response.Write "<label for = 'partsTxtBox' class = 'col-sm-4 col-form-label' name='"& PartsDesc &"'>" & PartsDesc & " </label>"
 %>
```

I want to insert the label name in **XXXXX** position in the email body. How can I do that?

Comment: You will have to add a hidden input field with the same value (PartsDesc) which can be accessed when submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Values can be bounded in same manner everywhere. Read about [variables](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_variables.asp).

You already have this

```
Dim PartsDesc
PartsDesc = request.querystring("partsdesc") 

<%
Response.Write "<label for = 'partsTxtBox' class = 'col-sm-4 col-form-label' name='"& PartsDesc &"'>" & PartsDesc & " </label>"
%>
```

where `PartsDesc` is your variable, that has the value. If this is the required value for the email body then move the following line to be after the code where the value is assigned and use it in same manner

```
objMessage.TextBody=objMessage.TextBody & PartsDesc & ": " & Request("Parts") & vbCrLf
```

If all now works as expected, read about [XSS](http://Filtering%20Encoded%20XSS%20in%20Classic%20ASP).